# Progress dialog freeze at the middle of the process

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'm trying to show a progress dialog while the process is running then dismiss after the process is done. But the dialog freezes before the process is done. What do i need to add in my code?

Here is my code:

```
final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "","Loading..Wait.." , true);
        switch (th.getCurrentTab()) {
        case 0:
            dialog.show();
            Handler menHanlder = new Handler();
            menHanlder.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    for(int i = 0; i < menLV.getCount(); i++)
                    {
                        if(menBooleanArray.get(i) == true) 
                        {
                            selectedFromMenList.add(menLV.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                        }
                    }
                    handler.setItemListData(WardrobeActivity.this, "Wardrobe", selectedFromMenList, "Name" , "Men" , "Type");
                    displayView();
                    drawer.closeMenu();
                    refreshTabWidget();
                    selectedFromMenList.clear();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }   
            }, 3000);
            break;
```

Does my approach in using the dialog is bad?

Any comment will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your progress Bar is freezing in between because you are processing heavy task on the UI thread and in Android you should not process the heavy tasks on UI thread instead you can use the `AsyncTask` for this purpose as follows:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{


 @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
//Show progress Dialog here

      }


@Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Voidresult) {
           //Update UI here if needed
//Dismiss Progress Dialog here
      }

 @Override
      protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //Do you heavy task here

      }      

}
```

**AsyncTask goes through 4 steps**

`onPreExecute()` invoked on the UI thread immediately after the task is executed.

`doInBackground(Param ...)` invoked on the background thread immediately after `onPreExecute()` finishes executing.

`onProgressUpdate(Progress...)` invoked on the UI thread after a call to `publishProgress(Progress...)`.

`onPostExecute(Result)` invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes.

**and start `AsyncTask` as follows:**

```
 new MyTask().execute();
```

Comment: A new approach to me. Thanks but how do i implement it? it will be an inner class or a separate class? and my progress dialog is on click so you mean i put my listener inside that inner class?

Comment: See as this would be a new technique for you , So you make it as a inner class , later you can learn to make it as a separate class also

Comment: I see, a button will trigger the progress bar and i will be depend on what tabhost is currently selected so do i put my onClick listener inside the doInBackground method there? and i think that it will be complicated if i do..

Comment: See this ASync task will be a inner class...On click of your button you will just execute the async task using  **new MyTask().execute()**
and then automatically all the methods of ASync task will be executed one after another....Check this link for more understanding on ASync task
http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2012/11/asynctask-android-example-asynctask-in.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25574/discussion-between-user1708134-and-karan-rana)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation

In Asynctask onPreExecute() I show the progress dialog like this

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ContentActivity.this);
        progressDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.show();

    }
```

Than it onPostExecute() with call when your task in doInBackground is done. I dismiss the progress dialog like this

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(BlognoneContent result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ..............
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            .............

}
```